# Apache httpd does not implement updates to a 301 redirect configuration

Tags: httpd, 301-redirect

I'm having a problem updating a previously-working redirect in my apache server (httpd, rhel).  I'd previously had:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/apidocs/ /old/specific/path/apidocs/
```

which worked.

I changed it to:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/apidocs/ /new/specific/path/apidocs/
```

and now it does not work.  That is, when I try to hit the simple http://<host>/apidocs url, I get a 301 with the old redirect location in the response headers, followed by a 404 in the browser, when it attempts to GET from the old location.  The httpd error-log corroborates that the browser tried to GET the old directory:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/html/old
```

Doing `service httpd reload` or `service httpd force-reload` produces only the following single line of output:

```
Reloading httpd:
```

...so it is presumably successful. Also,

(1) when httpd is started, its error log has no complaints.
(2) running `apachectl configtest` produces `Syntax OK`.
(3) running `httpd -t` produces `Syntax OK`.
(4) I've stopped and 'graceful' started httpd a number of times, to no avail.
(5) I've tried using apachectl -k stop/start, to no avail.

**(6) I have now also tried clearing the cache using htcacheclean, to no avail.**
*worth noting here that previously though the mod cache and mod cache disk modules were loaded, there was no configuration of the CacheRoot & etc, thus I added the following:*

```
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot "/var/cache/httpd"
CacheDirLength 2
CacheDirLevels 2
```

*...and subsequently verified it was being populated and cleared it with htcacheclean.*

**Where else might this stale 301 data be perpetuated??**

Thanks!
Hans

Comment: if you revert your configuration change, would it work then? if you run `httpd -t` it should provide you config file with line # where there is syntax error.

Comment: edited my original post, edited portion is in **bold**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...so the "answer" is that *the premise of the question is wrong.*  That is, apache httpd is doing its job correctly.  The real issue is that *there is a caching tier somewhere between httpd on the server and my local machine.*  I take as evidence of this that:
1. a wget executed from my local machine is redirected to the old redirect-url, while
2. a wget executed from the server is correctly redirected to the new redirect-url,
and the access logs for the former look like:

```
"GET /old/specific/path/apidocs/ HTTP/1.1" 404
```

whereas the latter produced:

```
"GET /apidocs/ HTTP/1.0" 301
"GET /new/specific/path/apidocs/ HTTP/1.0" 200
```

Comment: You can use curl to try and force a cache eviction. `curl -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -i http://yourhost/apidocs`. Repeat for the destination URLs too. Big limitation though is the Vary header. If you have 'Vary: User-Agent', then you'd have to repeat for all the various User-Agent strings (yow!). Similarly for 'Vary: Accept-Encoding' (better, but still quite a lot). Suggest you post the response headers to the lookup that gives the 301, and the subsequent request.

Comment: @Cameron Kerr Thx for the tip. not yet an avid curl user, but aspire to be better. command results are:
`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)  
Location: http://<server>/old/specific/path/apidocs/  
Content-Length: 172  
Content-Type: text/html  
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 20:24:41 GMT  
Age: 85845  
X-Cisco: WAE  
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv='content-type'   content='text/html;charset=utf-8'><TITLE>301 Moved   Permanently</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>301 Moved   Permanently</H1></BODY></HTML>`

Comment: Note the Age header, which indicates a cached response. It's also been through some Cisco appliance, which may be doing some caching (I'm not fimiliar with what WAEay mean)

Comment: Ah, Cisco WAN Accelleration Engine. I'd be very surprised if there wasn't some caching tricks going on there. I regularly find curl to be my most useful tool for diagnosis and validation for reverse-proxies and caching.

Comment: yep.  Darn, I should've seen that.  oh well, twas a long day.  At any rate, not surprised as a subsequent call to trace route shows a circuitous path from my box to the server--that's what ya get on a network managed by others--surprises!

Answer (score 0):

first thing first, you need to address syntax error, so run `httpd -t`, like this (except for echo part), this way you can figure out which config file contains syntax error:

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 conf.d]# echo blah >> php.conf 
[root@wcmisdlin02 conf.d]# httpd -t
AH00526: Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:
Invalid command 'blah', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[root@wcmisdlin02 conf.d]#
```

According to [mod_alias - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), your `RedirectMatch` seems fine. Are you accessing right Virtual Host?

Comment: `httpd: Syntax error on line 149 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/CA/webagent/bin/libmod_sm22.so into server: libsmerrlog.so cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`  
Thing is - I've made both those libraries AND the containing directory (1) owned by apache, and (2) 777.....

Comment: And as I'd feared, commenting out the invalid conf line remediates the http -t error, but does not fix the broken redirect.  I'll update my original post to reflect this now.

Comment: you should either address this error or comment it out, as otherwise `httpd` won't start after reboot.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done.  It is commented out, and the error no longer appears.  However, the redirect is still broken. :(

Comment: whatever you commented out has no effect on your redirect. I believe you're accessing it wrong, do one simple redirect and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not sure how to make my redirect any simpler...  it's just redirecting from one local directory url to another.  It worked before, and all I've changed is a couple elements in the (local) path of the redirect-to url.  
_interesting thing is..._ creating a new redirect, pointed at the new local uri (`RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/ /new/specific/path/apidocs`) works fine.  
so maybe _permanent_ really means **PERMANENT**??  I guess there must be some server-side 'routing-table' or cache that needs clearing...? (cleared my browser repeatedly, which logs reflect)

Comment: looks like apache does indeed cache 301s, and looks like **htcacheclean** is the tool to use to remedy this - now I just have to figure out how to use it correctly...

Comment: ha! that doesn't work either...  original post will, again, be amended with additional information...